# Why is Angular-Core throwing "Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule"

Tags: angular

So first I know there have been a few posts, but my issue doesn't seem related (tried a bunch and even used some). I am also new to this project, and I haven't done Angular quite like this before (so please be kind)

The project bootstraps like...

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApplicationModule,
  ],
  ...
})
```

My code gets to this Angular function...

```
CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getTypeMetadata = function (type, dependencies, throwOnUnknownDeps) {
    if (dependencies === void 0) { dependencies = null; }
    if (throwOnUnknownDeps === void 0) { throwOnUnknownDeps = true; }
    var identifier = this._getIdentifierMetadata(type);
    return {
        reference: identifier.reference,
        diDeps: this._getDependenciesMetadata(identifier.reference, dependencies, throwOnUnknownDeps),
        lifecycleHooks: getAllLifecycleHooks(this._reflector, identifier.reference),
    };
};
```

And identifier is

```
reference: ƒ ApplicationModule(appRef)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
ɵinj: {providers: Array(9), imports: Array(0), factory: ƒ}
length: 1
name: "ApplicationModule"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__annotations__: [DecoratorFactory]
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: core.js:30477
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
```

For all I can tell this is the ApplicationModule from the Angular core library which mean Angular itself is failing.

Why would Angular cause my app to fail in this way?

Comment: could you share the whole code in the resolver service file?

Comment: If you can be a little clearer what that means I would be happy to oblige. Just not sure which parts you think would matter.

Comment: I mean the file that contains this CompileMetadataResolver, could you share the whole code in that file?

Comment: That is after babel. Let me see if I can find where it comes from